# A Loop Inside Of An If Statement Inside Of Two Loops

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub aaa()
Dim childROWmax    As Long
Dim parentROWmax   As Long
Dim i              As Long
Dim j              As Long
Dim z              As Long
Dim p              As Long
Dim n              As Long
Dim parentPATTERN  As Range
Dim parentPATTERN2 As Range
Dim parentWEIGHT   As Range
Dim childPATTERN   As Range
Dim oMAX           As Range
Dim oMIN           As Range
Dim childCODE      As Range
Dim parentPART     As Range
Dim newPART        As String
Dim newSHEET       As Worksheet
Dim oldSHEET       As Worksheet

Set oldSHEET = ActiveSheet
parentROWmax = oldSHEET.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set newSHEET = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
             ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    newSHEET.Name = "Result"
childROWmax = Sheets("TitleHelper").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
MHTROWmax = newSHEET.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


    For i = 2 To parentROWmax
        z = 1
        n = 0

        'Increment Result sheet row
        MHTROWmax = MHTROWmax + 1

        'get MHT row info for comparison
           Set parentPATTERN = oldSHEET.Range("J" & i)
           Set parentPATTERN2 = oldSHEET.Range("K" & i)
           Set parentWEIGHT = oldSHEET.Range("H" & i)
           Set parentPART = oldSHEET.Range("A" & i)

        'Write a row to MHT Result Table
        oldSHEET.Rows(i).Copy newSHEET.Rows(MHTROWmax)

        For j = 2 To childROWmax

            'get TitleHelper row info for comparison
            Set childPATTERN = Worksheets("TitleHelper").Range("A" & j)
            Set oMAX = Worksheets("TitleHelper").Range("C" & j)
            Set oMIN = Worksheets("TitleHelper").Range("B" & j)
            Set childCODE = Worksheets("TitleHelper").Range("F" & j)
            newPART = parentPART & "*" & childCODE

            'Perform if/then
            If (parentPATTERN = childPATTERN _
                Or parentPATTERN2 = childPATTERN) _
               And parentWEIGHT <= oMAX _
               And parentWEIGHT >= oMIN _
               And z < 5 Then
                   z = z + 1

                'Increment Result sheet row
                MHTROWmax = MHTROWmax + 1

                'Criteria is met, write a row to MHT Result Table
                oldSHEET.Rows(i).Copy newSHEET.Rows(MHTROWmax)
                newSHEET.Cells(MHTROWmax, 1) = newPART
                    For p = 2 To childROWmax

                         If (parentPATTERN = Worksheets("TitleHelper").Range("A" & p) _
                          Or parentPATTERN2 = Worksheets("TitleHelper").Range("A" & p)) _
                          And parentWEIGHT <= Worksheets("TitleHelper").Range("C" & p) _
                          And parentWEIGHT >= Worksheets("TitleHelper").Range("B" & p) _
                         And n < 4 Then
                             n = n + 1

                          newSHEET.Cells(MHTROWmax, 19 + n) = Worksheets("TitleHelper").Range("E" & p).Value
                         End If
                    Next p
                End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

So i have this VBA code where it loops through a sheet (oldSHEET)
for each row in oldSHEET it will add a row to newSHEET
then it will copy the row over to the new row
then it will loop through a different sheet (TitleHelper)
for each row in TitleHelper it will go through an IF statement
If the statement is true it will add a row to newSHEET
then it will copy the row over to the new row
then it will replace the first cell in the new row with newPART
then it will loop through TitleHelper again
for each row in TitleHelper it will go through an IF statement
If the statement is true it will replace the 19th + n column on the new row

that should be the end of the code, but if i put the end of the first IF statement above the P Loop it will only do the 19th + n replacement on the first iteration of the J Loop because of "MHTROWmax = MHTROWmax + 1"

If the first IF statement ends before "Next P" with the second IF statement it gives me an error code.

If the If statements remain how they are it will write the 19th + n replacement on the first iteration of the J loop and then do some weird stuff for the other iterations.

I've included a copy of my worksheet
just use the macro when "MHT" is active
(EDIT: added the result page as it should appear. note: you would have to change the name of "result" to run the macro)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZbmcIr_bRp_f6cngMeZevj7zujcdW1RC/view?usp=sharing

Here is an image of the expected result as well
[Expected Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9BaM.png)

Comment: Your question is so complex I'm not even sure if I understand it. A general word of advise: break your code up into pieces. For example, if a condition in your first loop matches, take the values of the row and store them in a range object. Then pass that range object to a separate function, perform your second loop, edit the range object (or not), then insert the Range object in the new sheet.

Comment: First error I see is in getting the last row for your sheets, `Rows.Count` evaluates to `ActiveSheet.Rows.Count`, for example: `Sheets("TitleHelper").Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`, which I bet is not what you want.

Comment: @FAB that doesnt seem to cause any issues. If i remove the "for p =" loop everything works as intended. Its just the P loop inside of the first if statement thats giving me problems

Comment: @Amo van Boven so store "oldSHEET.Rows(i).Copy newSHEET.Rows(MHTROWmax)" as a range object and pass it on to a different sub/function that replaces the first cell with newPART. Then store that as a range object and pass it on to a different sub/function that adds the 19th + n values? that sounds like it would work. thank you for the advice i'll try that.

Comment: @FAB I see what you mean, but wouldn't the activesheet be newSHEET since `Set newSHEET = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
             ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))` would activate the sheet?

Comment: @BuhBlake my bad, I had in my mind that should always use `sheet.Rows.Count`, but just realised that it doesn't matter given that in any sheet the `Rows.Count` will be the same lol.

Comment: @BuhBlake any chance you can include a screenshot to show how you want your output to look? Few rows should do, especially around your 19th + n.  By the way, add `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the begininng, and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end to speed up.

Comment: @FAB added a screenshot and changed the workbook link to include a version of expected results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so i figured it out by actually taking the last loop (p loop) and looping it again with the i loop. So its actually 2 double loops instead of 1 triple loop. Theres definitely a better way to do this, but i'm glad i figured out any fix at all.

**So basically the first two loops:**

- loops through oldSHEET

- Adds a copied row to newSHEET from oldSHEET

- Loops through TitleHelper

- If statement is true then adds a copied row to newSHEET from oldSHEET

- Change the first cell of the new row to newPART

Then i change the values of oldSHEET and newSHEET to "Result" and a new sheet "Result2"

**The second two loops:**

- loops through oldSHEET

- Adds a copied row to newSHEET from oldSHEET

- Loops through TitleHelper

- If statement is true then replace the 19th + n column on the new row

```
Sub ParentPartOne()
    Dim childROWmax    As Long
    Dim parentROWmax   As Long
    Dim i              As Long
    Dim j              As Long
    Dim z              As Long
    Dim p              As Long
    Dim parentPATTERN  As Range
    Dim parentPATTERN2 As Range
    Dim parentWEIGHT   As Range
    Dim childPATTERN   As Range
    Dim oMAX           As Range
    Dim oMIN           As Range
    Dim childCODE      As Range
    Dim parentPART     As Range
    Dim newPART        As String
    Dim newSHEET       As Worksheet
    Dim oldSHEET       As Worksheet

    Set oldSHEET = ActiveSheet
    parentROWmax = oldSHEET.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set newSHEET = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
                                           ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    newSHEET.Name = "Result"
    childROWmax = Sheets("TitleHelper").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    MHTROWmax = newSHEET.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


    For i = 2 To parentROWmax
        z = 1
        n = 0

       'Increment Result sheet row
        MHTROWmax = MHTROWmax + 1

       'get MHT row info for comparison
        Set parentPATTERN = oldSHEET.Range("J" & i)
        Set parentPATTERN2 = oldSHEET.Range("K" & i)
        Set parentWEIGHT = oldSHEET.Range("H" & i)
        Set parentPART = oldSHEET.Range("A" & i)

       'Write a row to MHT Result Table
        oldSHEET.Rows(i).Copy newSHEET.Rows(MHTROWmax)

        For j = 2 To childROWmax

           'get TitleHelper row info for comparison
            Set childPATTERN = Worksheets("TitleHelper").Range("A" & j)
            Set oMAX = Worksheets("TitleHelper").Range("C" & j)
            Set oMIN = Worksheets("TitleHelper").Range("B" & j)
            Set childCODE = Worksheets("TitleHelper").Range("F" & j)
            newPART = parentPART & "*" & childCODE

           'Perform if/then
            If (parentPATTERN = childPATTERN _
            Or parentPATTERN2 = childPATTERN) _
            And parentWEIGHT <= oMAX _
            And parentWEIGHT >= oMIN _
            And z < 5 Then
                z = z + 1

               'Increment Result sheet row
                MHTROWmax = MHTROWmax + 1

               'Criteria is met, write a row to MHT Result Table
                oldSHEET.Rows(i).Copy newSHEET.Rows(MHTROWmax)
                newSHEET.Cells(MHTROWmax, 1) = newPART
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    Set oldSHEET = Sheets("Result")
    parentROWmax = oldSHEET.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set newSHEET = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
                                           ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    newSHEET.Name = "Result2"
    childROWmax = Sheets("TitleHelper").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    MHTROWmax = newSHEET.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To parentROWmax
        z = 1
        n = 0

       'Increment Result sheet row
        MHTROWmax = MHTROWmax + 1

       'get MHT row info for comparison
        Set parentPATTERN = oldSHEET.Range("J" & i)
        Set parentPATTERN2 = oldSHEET.Range("K" & i)
        Set parentWEIGHT = oldSHEET.Range("H" & i)
        Set parentPART = oldSHEET.Range("A" & i)

       'Write a row to MHT Result Table
        oldSHEET.Rows(i).Copy newSHEET.Rows(MHTROWmax)

        For p = 2 To childROWmax

        If (parentPATTERN = Worksheets("TitleHelper").Range("A" & p) _
        Or parentPATTERN2 = Worksheets("TitleHelper").Range("A" & p)) _
        And parentWEIGHT <= Worksheets("TitleHelper").Range("C" & p) _
        And parentWEIGHT >= Worksheets("TitleHelper").Range("B" & p) _
        And n < 4 Then
            n = n + 1

                newSHEET.Cells(MHTROWmax, 19 + n) = Worksheets("TitleHelper").Range("E" & p).Value
            End If
        Next p
    next i

End Sub
```